# criteria api multiselect with count and distinct not working

Tags: java, sql, jpa

```
SELECT a.id,COUNT(entity2.number) 
AS "numbers" ,SUM(CASE WHEN entity2.status= 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS "blocked" FROM entity1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity ON a.id = entity2.id
WHERE a.id LIKE 'ZX13%'
GROUP BY a.id.
```

i am using criteria builder api to perform above operation.

If i use `criteriaQuery.multiselect(listSelections).groupBy(a.id)` it works fine but when i use `criteriaQuery.multiselect(listSelections).distinct(true).groupBy(a.id)` it is not working fine. I want distinct results too.

Why it is not working as expected?
How to resolve this?

Comment: "not working". And what does your debugging say about WHAT is "not working"? What SQL was generated by your JPA provider? You have looked at their log, haven't you?

Comment: Hi.thanks for the reply..I will show you log details.

Comment: Hi @BillyFrost. I got to know the problem. distinct  was applying to all the select statements for count and sum fucntions too.   hence it was throwing sql exception

Comment: so post all of that, and the SQL in the QUESTION, not in a COMMENT.